# Using .once between components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am using .Once to have a method fire only once but my application allows a user to go back and forth between steps(components) and once a user has switched component and then goes back the method is able to fire again.

I've tried just using a boolean stored in the $store data (Vuex) and having it check that to only have it fire once but it throws off the rest of the application. I'm not sure how adding an if statement interacts with the rest of the methods firing.

```
<select v-model="updateActiveKeyword" @click.once="restOfAds()">
   <option
     v-for="option in options"
     :key="option.id"
     @input="dropDownSelect(option)"
     :bind="option"
     style="padding: 3px 80px;"
     >{{option}}</option>
   </select>
```

I'm thinking there might be an easier way to utilize .Once that I haven't found an answer to online yet where the component can change.

Comment: Awesome, thanks it worked out! From what I'm reading about this, it may not seem like best practice but considering there isn't much data or any API calls in this component it should work out fine. Thanks again

Comment: The other alternative is indeed to store globally that the button has been clicked already and read that.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to use the `<keep-alive>` component, so the components aren't rendered again when you move from one to the other, and that .once event listener may run only once since it's the same instance.

Check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/2bcnesxo).

You can read more on `<keep-alive>` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components)

It has its own caveats that you should be aware of, like the caching of the component instance and the lifecycle hooks execution.